# Speech recognition in Unity 5 for Android

Tags: unity, android

I've been working on a game in which the player have to say particular words to perform various tasks. For example, if the player says "boat", a boat pops up in the game. The game I'm building is specifically for offline play, on an Android device. Just for reference, there is a game titled "Pah!" which implemented this offline speech recognition for one specific word. In this game, when you say "pah", the GameObject moves jumps.

I've tried everything from speech-to-text to forums, and even tried Google and used using `Windows.Speech`, but nothing works. From what I've learned, I need to use the Google speech API for Android speech recognition. I am a bit new, when it comes to Java. I gave it a try and created a basic script, which I thought might take at least one input in speech from the player, but Unity disagrees and says it couldn't recognize the script. I created another script in C#, by taking help from tutorials, but when I switch the platform from Windows to Android it doesn't work, because `Unity.Windows.Speech` is a Windows namespace

I am blank, and hence, this question. I have googled, visited forums, and even looked at YouTube videos for an answer. I came across a few Unity assets which I paid for, and they are all garbage. If anyone could help me, how do I implement speech recognition in Android, using Unity 5?

Comment: God talk about complex lol, if anyone finds a solution i will be surprised. I don't see it being something easily done.

Comment: @Ryanwhite, yeah, I understand that it is really difficult to achieve but hey! someone did that already so it must be achievable. :)

Comment: Yeah it must be, its just such a big task

Comment: I find the solution using IBM watson speech to text services,but it take some time to load it from server and then send it to user.
even there is unity SDK is available on github and also on asset store.